# What technical/legal responsibilities do I have when hosting images uploaded by others?

Tags: image, licensing

You may argue that this question has a legal flavor to it, and that would be correct. Still, it is also a question from a developer's perspective that may help others.

I'm building an image community web site/application. Users can upload images. During upload, users have to select the license (copyrighted, attribution non-commercial or public domain). No matter which license they choose, it is just a piece of data. No matter the license, all users can view all images and also download all images, as you normally do on websites.

My question is: what responsibility do I have as a "platform" to comply with these licenses?

- Do I need to actively prevent certain actions on these images, and into what extend?
- Is displaying the license enough to be legally safe?
- What if one of my users uploads images for which he has no license? Is it enough to just implement a "report this" feature?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Your question is specific to a country - each country has its own rules.
- Best way to know what to do - get the legal notes from sites like Picasa, Facebook, etc, and read them.
- Usually a legal notice to the users is enough - as long as you have an active mail that can get request from content owners to remove their content from the site if it is there without permission and you response immediately - then I Think you are good to go.

Comment: Thank you, I intended to do those things anyway so this answer comforts me. One final thing on my mind is to find out what license permits uploading an image on behalf of an owner, I'm guess only attribution licenses allow this.

Comment: Again - it is depends if you want to be ok with US Law, China Law, Iran Law - every country has it's own rules about it. I know that here (where I live) - you need to respond to request in a timely manner and you are covered - and if you don't you are might be facing a civil law-suit, which usually ends before getting to court. You should consult a lawyer about your local country rules.

Comment: Thanks again for enriching the answer. When you say local country rules do you mean the rules that apply in the country of the platform/hoster or the rules of the country of the owner of a photograph?

Answer (score 1):

- No, not by any jurisdiction I know of. Make sure people sign a paper (electornically) and agree on only lawfull use (get a lawyer define it).
- No, but it is a good step towards it.
- No, it is not enough. You ALSO must react to those reports.

Depending on country you may have other obligations - like in the US there is a legal process to ask the hoster to take down documents, so you bettre know how to wwork if you fall under US jurisdiction.

In general, the above is a rough guideline, but you SHOULD ask a lawyer for the details.